# Is there a way for a view to know when it's fully inflated?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In iOS, when "inflating" a view from a nib file (the iOS equivalent of an Android layout.xml file), the view's 'awakeFromNib' method is called. It's only called one time, unlike measure, etc.

Is there an equivalent of awakeFromNib in Android?

Our need is to be able to assign child views loaded from the layout to member variables on the View subclass.  Yes, we can do this externally, but we're trying to make the views self-manage its own members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [overriding `onFinishInflate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate()).

Comment: Duh! [head-slap!!]. How on earth did I miss that?  Thanks!